# extra line spacing in the converted docx file using PHPword and simplehtmldom

Tags: docx, fckeditor, simple-html-dom, phpword

I am using PHPword and simplehtmldom to convert html to docx format.

I am using fckeditor html output as the input for converting to docx. A single line break is reflected as multiple lines in the docx converted file.

How do i fix this ? The enter key used in fckeditor is adding a  tag in the html output. Is there any number of line breaks defined for a para tag. how do i change it or where do i change it.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

This should help: http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/discussions/401122

or

You can comment-out:

```
$phpword_element->addTextBreak();
```

in h2d_htmlconverter.php found in line 357